# Python group by multiple keys in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dict I want to group by multiple keys.

I have used sort by default in python dict

```
data = [
[],
[{'value': 8, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 9, 'year': 2020}, {'value': 79, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020}, {'value': 126, 'bot': 'DB', 'month':8, 'year': 2021}],
[],
[{'value': 222, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020}, {'value': 623, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}, {'value': 628, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 9, 'year': 2021}],
[{'value': 0, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}],
[{'value': 703, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020}, {'value': 1081, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 3, 'year': 2021}, {'value': 1335, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020}, {'value': 1920, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}, {'value': 2132, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 1, 'year': 2021}, {'value': 2383, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 2, 'year': 2021}]
]

output_dict = {}

for i in data:
    if not i:
        pass
    for j in i:
        for key,val in sorted(j.items()):
            output_dict.setdefault(val, []).append(key)

            
print(output_dict)
    
{'DB': ['bot', 'bot', 'bot', 'bot', 'bot', 'bot', 'bot', 'bot', 'bot'], 9: ['month', 'month', 'month'], 8: ['value'], 2020: ['year', 'year', 'year', 'year', 'year'], 10: ['month', 'month'], 79: ['value'], 126: ['value'], 2021: ['year', 'year', 'year', 'year', 'year', 'year', 'year', 'year'], 'GEMBOT': ['bot', 'bot', 'bot', 'bot'], 11: ['month', 'month'], 222: ['value'], 4: ['month', 'month', 'month'], 623: ['value'], 628: ['value'], 0: ['value'], 703: ['value'], 3: ['month'], 1081: ['value'], 1335: ['value'], 1920: ['value'], 1: ['month'], 2132: ['value'], 2: ['month'], 2383: ['value']}
```

But I want the output like this.

```
[{ "bot": "DB",
   "date": "Sept 20",
   "value": 134
},{"bot": "DB",
   "date": "Oct 20",
   "value": 79
}.. So on ]
```

Is there an efficient way to flatten this list ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no date field in the input

Comment: check out [pdb - The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to debug small programs `python3 -m pdb myscript.py` .. use `b` to set a breakpoint (so you can inspect your program there), `c` to run up to that point (continue), and `?` to explore commands .. this will allow you to inspect the live state of your program wherever you breakpoint or continue to

Comment: Yes there is no date input there is only month, based on the month and year date is obtained. @DaniMesejo

Comment: Perhaps you could write a better example of what you want

Comment: I'm trying to break my head on this since 2 days. This is exactly my usecase @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things will make this easier to answer. The first is a list comprehension that will promote sub-items:

```
data_reshaped = [cell for row in data for cell in row]
```

this will take your original `data` and flatten it a bit to:

```
[
    {'value': 8, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 9, 'year': 2020},
    {'value': 79, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020},
    {'value': 126, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 8, 'year': 2021},
    {'value': 222, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020},
    {'value': 623, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021},
    {'value': 628, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 9, 'year': 2021},
    {'value': 0, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021},
    {'value': 703, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020},
    {'value': 1081, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 3, 'year': 2021},
    {'value': 1335, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020},
    {'value': 1920, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021},
    {'value': 2132, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 1, 'year': 2021},
    {'value': 2383, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 2, 'year': 2021}
]
```

Now we can iterate over that using an compound key and `setdefault()` to aggregate the results. Note if you rather use `collections.defaultdict()` as I do then swap that out for `setdefault()`.

```
results = {}
for cell in data_reshaped:
    key = f"{cell['bot']}_{cell['year']}_{cell['month']}"
    value = cell["value"] # save the value so we can reset cell next
    cell["value"] = 0 # setting this to 0 cleans up the next line.
    results.setdefault(key, cell)["value"] += value
```

This should allow you to:

```
for result in results.values():
    print(result)
```

**Giving:**

```
{'value': 8, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 9, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 1414, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 126, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 8, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 222, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 623, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 628, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 9, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 703, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 1081, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 3, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 1920, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 2132, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 1, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 2383, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 2, 'year': 2021}
```

**Full solution:**

```
data = [
    [],
    [
        {'value': 8, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 9, 'year': 2020},
        {'value': 79, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020},
        {'value': 126, 'bot': 'DB', 'month':8, 'year': 2021}
    ],
    [],
    [
        {'value': 222, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020},
        {'value': 623, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021},
        {'value': 628, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 9, 'year': 2021}
    ],
    [
        {'value': 0, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}
    ],
    [
        {'value': 703, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020},
        {'value': 1081, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 3, 'year': 2021},
        {'value': 1335, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020},
        {'value': 1920, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021},
        {'value': 2132, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 1, 'year': 2021},
        {'value': 2383, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 2, 'year': 2021}
    ]
]

data_reshaped = [cell for row in data for cell in row]

results = {}
for cell in data_reshaped:
    key = f"{cell['bot']}_{cell['year']}_{cell['month']}"
    value = cell["value"]
    cell["value"] = 0
    results.setdefault(key, cell)["value"] += value

for result in results.values():
    print(result)
```

**Again Giving:**

```
{'value': 8, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 9, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 1414, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 10, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 126, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 8, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 222, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 623, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 628, 'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'month': 9, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 703, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 11, 'year': 2020}
{'value': 1081, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 3, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 1920, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 4, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 2132, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 1, 'year': 2021}
{'value': 2383, 'bot': 'DB', 'month': 2, 'year': 2021}
```

I will leave it to you to figure out casting the two date fields to some other presentation as that seems out of context with the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
from pprint import pprint
import datetime

output_dict = []

for i in data:
  if i:
    for j in i:
      for key, val in sorted(j.items()):
        if key == "bot":
          temp["bot"] = val
        elif key == "value":
          temp["value"] = val
        elif key == "month":
          month = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(val), "%m")
          temp["date"] = month.strftime("%b")
        elif key == "year":
          temp["date"] = str(temp["date"]) + " " + str(val)
      output_dict.append(temp)
      temp = {}

pprint(output_dict)
```

The final results are shown as follows:

```
[{'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Sep 2020', 'value': 8},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Oct 2020', 'value': 79},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Aug 2021', 'value': 126},
 {'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'date': 'Nov 2020', 'value': 222},
 {'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'date': 'Apr 2021', 'value': 623},
 {'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'date': 'Sep 2021', 'value': 628},
 {'bot': 'GEMBOT', 'date': 'Apr 2021', 'value': 0},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Nov 2020', 'value': 703},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Mar 2021', 'value': 1081},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Oct 2020', 'value': 1335},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Apr 2021', 'value': 1920},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Jan 2021', 'value': 2132},
 {'bot': 'DB', 'date': 'Feb 2021', 'value': 2383}]
```

Comment: Thank u it works

Comment: @user9538877 It does not work if you wanted was a single `{'bot': 'DB', 'date': '10 2020', 'value': 1414}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
output = []
for i in data:
    if not i:
        pass
    for j in i:
        output.append(j)
```

And then if you want to sort it, then you can use `sorted_output = sorted(ouput, key=lambda k: k['bot'])`  to sort it by `bot` for example. If you want to sort it by date, maybe create a value that calculates the date in months and then sorts it from there.

Comment: Interesting idea let me check it out

Comment: You could maybe add a date in months by doing: `sorted_output = sorted(ouput, key=lambda k: k['year']*12 + k['month'])` or simply instead of storing the date in months and years, just storing it in years and then calculating the years seperately.